# Maven Dependency Analyzer: How to solve problems with scope 'provided'?

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-dependency-plugin

I've started using `maven-dependency-plugin:analyze-only` in our build to clean up POMs. Basically we want all dependencies to be declared in the POM and not rely on transitive dependencies that would be used for compiling.

This works well, but I'm having problems with the `provided` scope. We have defined a POM that contains all the Java EE dependencies (we're using JBoss EAP). All the JEE APIs must have `provided` scope, of course. That's why we do the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>foobar</groupId>
  <artifactId>jee7-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

This contains

```
<groupId>foobar</groupId>
<artifactId>jee7-api</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-eap-parent</artifactId>
      <version>${jboss-eap-parent.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
      <version>${jboss-javaee-7.0.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-batch-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ... etc. etc.
</dependencies>
```

That works well for the build, but the Dependency Analyzer is moaning:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:analyze-only (analyze-dependencies) @ my-project ---
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-1:provided
[WARNING]    javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1.0.0.redhat-6:provided
[WARNING]    javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-1:provided
[WARNING]    xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:test
[WARNING]    javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.2.0.redhat-2:provided
[WARNING]    org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-1:provided
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm aware that I could switch on the plugin's `ignoreNonCompile`, but I want to check **all** dependency scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence and javaee-api (version 7) and I could get rid of the warnings simply by changing the order of appearance in the pom. I put the javax.persistence dependency before the javaee-api dependency (which means the latter one has to come last if you have more than one warning).

PS: I don't use the pom artifact as you do...